# How to check the date format of the cell (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Please, help)

I need to verify that cells are populated with correct values.
I have a few types of column with a few format of value, i.e. '`2015-05-20Z`' and '`XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/2015-05-20`'.

I do not know how to check the date, if it is only part of the value.
This query work:

```
case 
when A like 'XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/%' 
then 'true' 
else 'false' 
end
```

But it doesn't enough...

This query doesn't work:

```
case 
when A like 'XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' 
then 'true' 
else 'false' 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
case 
    when regexp_like(A, 'XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]')
    then 'true' 
    else 'false' 
end
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to use `like` to match regular expressions. If that is your intent, look into [regexp_like](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) instead.

Comment: Thank you very match! It is working!

REGEXP_LIKE (A, '^XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$')

Comment: No problem. Clicking on the green check mark next to the answer is all the thanks I need :)