# How to check that cells contain data in date format (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need verify that all cells in column contain data in only date format. How it possible to verify? 
*I think it isn't LIKE function.

Comment: Column data type? You aren't storing dates as char/varchar...?

Comment: I have table POL with column TR_KRY and i need to verify that this column contain only date (e.g.15-02-2015) not:
15-02-2015Z
15-02-2015exit
A15-02-2015

Comment: Data_Type='VARCHAR(250 BYTE)

Comment: This is the most common mistake in database design I've found in my carreer. Dates stored in varchar2 columns because they don't understand how the DATE data type works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DATE** doesn't have any **format**. What you see is for display purpose so that it could be easily interpreted.

**DATE datatype** is stored in a **proprietary format internally** in `7 bytes`. It is a bad idea and makes no sense to verify the format while date is stored in an internal format. As I said, format is *only* for *display*.

If the date column is not a **DATE data type**, then it is a **design flaw**. And, any application based on such a **flawed database design** is on the verge to break anytime.

Storing DATE values other than date data type is just like not understanding the basics.

You should first fix the design to get a permanent solution. Any solution to your question is just another workaround.

Let me show a small example how it creates even more confusion.

The following date :

```
01/02/2015
```

Is it:

1. `1st Feb 2015` or,
2. `2nd Jan 2015`

There is no way to tell that. It could be either **DD** or **MM**. This being just one among so many other problems due to the incorrect data type.

> **Store date values as DATE data type only, period.**

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350596/how-to-check-the-date-format-of-the-cell-oracle/30350799#30350799), I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (A, '^XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$')
```

If count is greater than zero, something doesn't match. If you want more detail on what doesn't match, change your `SELECT` clause appropriately.

If you are looking for multiple date formats, you can change your regular expression appropriately. The `|` operator in most flavors of regular expression, including Oracle's, lets you define multiple patterns in the same space. You might use something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
WHERE NOT
REGEXP_LIKE (A,
  '^XXX/MOSCOW/XXXMSX/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$|^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$')
```

adding as many different matching patterns as you need.

Comment: but 2015-15-15Z doesn't match this select but not in date format.
I think that query below is not enough, because date can contain 15/15/2015 fromat or 2015/15/15
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}

Comment: Edited for your instruction. I suggest a regex tutorial.

Comment: What is `01/02/2015`? Is it `1st Feb 2015` or `2nd Jan 2015`? Is there any regex to interpret that?

Comment: @LalitKumarB agreed, but OP is asking for verification, not interpretation.

Comment: @Politank-Z OP will never be satisfied with any answer, because there isn't any practical solution to his design issues. Until and unless he fixes the design flaw. Hope you got my point.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I do get your point; however, one can not always control the formatting of one's input. Using the database to translate from inconsistent input to correct storage may not be the best solution. It certainly isn't the only solution. Sadly, it is a real world problem which the question may be a valid step toward solving.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM POL
  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(TR_KRY, '^(0[1-9]|([1-2][0-9])|30|31)-(([0][1-9])|10|11|12)-[0-9]{4}$')
```

This will return you all rows where TR_KRY is not formatted as 'DD-MM-YYYY', where DD is '01'-'31', MM is '01'-'12', and YYYY is any four numeric digits.

As others have said, storing dates as character strings is not a good idea. In the field you're looking at, it might be that the date is stored as DD-MM-YYYY (day-month-year - the usual case in Europe and perhaps elsewhere), or it might be that the date is stored as MM-DD-YYYY (month-day-year - a common practice in the US). If possible, I suggest you should convert this field to the DATE data type so that the TO_CHAR function can be used to produce a text version of the date in whatever format is desired.

Given the example data you've shown in comments (and that's also not good practice - you should go back and edit the question when you want to include additional information) it appears the dates are formatted as DD-MM-YYYY and I've set up the regular expression above to deal with this as best as possible.